# Disable Spotlight keyboard shortcut for selected applications

Tags: mac, keyboard-shortcuts, eclipse, spotlight

Spotlight search is activated by Ctrl+Space.

Unfortunately, this collides with code completion in Eclipse.

I could change the shortcut for either function, but I'd like to stick with the defaults.

Is there a way to disable the Spotlight shortcut when a given application is active (in this case Eclipse)?

Comment: It's actually `cmd+space` and, granted, I know there is a solution for this answer, but I couldn't find it right now.

Answer (score 6):

I don't think it is possible to disable the Spotlight shortcut just when a specific application is in focus. The closest thing for you to do would be to re-map the shortcut (either Spotlight's or Eclipse's).

To change the keyboard shortcut systemwide for Spotlight:

- In System Preferences, go to **Keyboard**, then **Keyboard Shortcuts**.
- In the column on the left, select **Spotlight**.
- Double click the shortcut (in this case **⌘ Space**) and hold down the new shortcut. I suggest something similar, such as option + Space.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Follow these steps:

1. System Preferences
2. Spotlight
3. Untick Spotlight menu keyboard shortcut

Answer (score 0):

Change the keyboard shortcut for showing the Spotlight menu to something like control-command-space:

[image]

Then use a [private.xml](http://pqrs.org/macosx/keyremap4macbook/xml.html.en) like this with KeyRemap4MacBook:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
  <appdef>
    <appname>ECLIPSE</appname>
    <equal>org.eclipse.eclipse</equal>
  </appdef>
  <item>
    <name>test</name>
    <identifier>test</identifier>
    <not>ECLIPSE</not>
    <autogen>__KeyToKey__ KeyCode::SPACE, VK_COMMAND | ModifierFlag::NONE,
    KeyCode::SPACE, ModifierFlag::CONTROL_L | ModifierFlag::COMMAND_L</autogen>
  </item>
</root>
```

Answer (score -2):

Sounds like a job for [Autohotkey](http://www.autohotkey.com/). Use the ifwinactive or ifwinexist functions. Can't yet work out the exact code, but shouldn't be too hard with a bit of time.

Comment: Umm… Spotlight is for OS X. Autohotkey is for Windows...

Comment: Whoops. Should have read closer sorry.

Comment: Think I read Spotlight as Silverlight.

Comment: There is an autohotkey for mac tho: Iron AHK http://code.google.com/p/ironahk/ and there's also an automator alternative that you can drag n' drop commands that resembles AHK, but I can't remember its name.